# Why do I get a 'None" Response for this? What does this mean exactly?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm getting into python and I don't quite understand the response formats after scraping a web. Why do I get none as a response for this code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND' 

page = requests.get(quote_page).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

price_box = soup.find('span', class_="priceText__1853e8a5")

price = price_box

print(price)
```

Comment: Your page is probably dynamically loaded with javascript so you may have to use Selenium to deal with it. Search around - this comes up a lot.

Comment: In case the page is dynamically loaded, you could also use rendertron and make a `requests.get` to this page instead of the normal page.

Comment: The content you wanna grab is static but within another class name. You can check it by inspecting page source. However, the page is redirecting you to somewhere else. Try this command to see `print(soup.title)` what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, this is not a problem with your code, the page does not contain a span element with the specific class you are looking for.

`soup` hold some representation of the page. You can print this representation out by doing `print(soup)`.

Next you are looking for the first `span` element that has a class `priceText__1853e8a5`. Unfortunately, there are no matches in the page, and so you are getting `None` as the answer. To see this, you can compare the results of finding all spans and finding a different element, for example:

```
print(soup.find_all('span'))
print(soup.find_all('a'))
```

I'm guessing that your problem is that this specific page is not static.
In that cause, your problem is that `requests.get(quote_page).text` does not return the page you want, but some intermediate page.

You can use a more complicated engine to go to this url for you. Here's a step-by-step example with Selenium & Firefox

1. Make sure you have firefox installed
2. Make sure you have [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) in your path (a quick and very dirty solution is having it in the same directory as the one you are running it)
3. Change your code to use this driver instead of a simple request, and the rest could stay the same

The resulting code would be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

quote_page = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND' 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

driver.quit()

price_box = soup.find('span', class_="priceText__1853e8a5")

price = price_box

print(price)
```